# How can I remove signal from a workspace in Seq logging UI?

Tags: seq-logging

In Seq, I created a personal workspace in order to reduce the number of signals I see. However, it seems not only signals created by other people in other workspaces are also visible (probably because they are shared or corporate level), but also I cannot remove them. Some of them are there by default, ex. log level. There is no "edit" option to "remove from workspace", and when there is, signal is simply not removed.
Is there a way to permanently remove signals, for example if I would like to have a workspace with no signal, or just my custom created ones (not default and not created by teammates)?

Comment: This one might need some screenshots for clarification, there are a few different ways I could imagine things going wrong. It should definitely be possible/straightforward to do what you're intending.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm facing the same problem.

I am attempting to have a Workspace per 'product' that my team manages. These are shared workspaces not personal ones.

When I create a signal, dashboard or alert in one of the workspaces it appears in all the others. If I use the 'remove from workspace' menu option it doesn't get removed.

It appears you can only remove the signal, alert or dashboard from all workspaces but not individually.

This appears to be contrary to Datalust's documentation:

> Workspaces help organize your view of Seq by collecting related signals, queries, and dashboards.

> There won't be any other signals in the workspace at this stage: add related signals by searching and selecting in the signal bar. Each signal can appear in any number of workspaces - adding a signal to one won't remove it from any others.

> To remove a signal, query, or dashboard from a workspace, use the pencil icon next to the thing you want to remove, and select "Remove from Workspace" in the drop-down menu beside the item's title.

https://docs.datalust.co/docs/workspaces